# Whats the default size of wizardfomr?

Tags: inno-setup

I would ask what is the default value of these parameters:

ClientWidth
ClientHeight

I think its near 497x360.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It varies based on the font size/DPI and the language in use, but the default is the same.
See the MSDN articles on dialog sclaing for specific details.